# Pagination and Native Query for Doctrine 2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I use Symfony and **Native Queries** Doctrine 2.

My queries are very hard (*Multiple joins, subqueries, ...*).

I want to add `LIMIT` for Pagination.

But `LIMIT` is executed for all tables; I want to execute only for first table.

Can you help me ?

Comment: hey Gaylord! some code snippets and some more explanation would be helpful if you want quality answers and not get flagged.

Comment: The easy approach is to use two queries.  The first one is for your table that you want to limit.  Then use the results to build the second query to get your final dataset,  In some cases you can combine the two using subqueries (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subqueries.html).

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for doctrine [pagination](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/pagination.html#pagination).

Hope this help you.

Comment: I dont think you can use it with createNativeQuery()